# Download Videos in a specific folder

Tags: android

I am working on app in which I have to download videos from server. I am using download manager because it will handle all the backend scenarios. The prooblem i am facing is videos are not downloading in my concern folder. i have created a folder using File..Any idea how would I get it ?

```
private void downloadVideos(String[] videosName, String moduleName) {

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + DatabaseHelper.PROJECT_NAME);
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists())
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    if (!success) return;

    folder = new File(folder.getPath() + File.separator + moduleName);
    if (!folder.exists())
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    if (!success) return;

    for (int i = 0; i < videosName.length; i++) {
        String fileName = videosName[i];
        File file = new File(folder.getPath(), fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "file already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(CONSTANTS.Video_URL + fileName + ".mp4");
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(file.getPath(), fileName)
                        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                        .setTitle("Downloading " + fileName);
                refID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Internet connectivity issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
    getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

}
```

Comment: do you have the appropriate permissions (write external storage)?

Comment: Yes I added! everything is working fine but only problem is to save videos in a specific folder using download manager!

Comment: `Yes I added!` including requesting runtime permissions?

Comment: thats not an issue for this..issue is different! as I mentioned everything is working fine..

Comment: @MustufaAnsari did you get answer for it?